# is there any  API for images?

Tags: php, jquery, web-services

I was looking for some API that given a query would return an image,

something like

```
<img src="http://webservice.com/?q=red+car" />
```

Or something more complex involving a request through API

Found [this one of google](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/image-search/&ei=GNYkT6jrNKrC0QX7kMHOCg&usg=AFQjCNHQj9-BhBRppICMQRqCdFhI_76wCQ&cad=rja) but is now deprecated,

any working known one?

Comment: Google for Flickr API...

Comment: I saw one recently but for the life of me I can't remember it.  What I'm saying though is, there is definitely one out there.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533857/whats-the-best-web-image-search-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flickr API http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

> flickr.photos.search
>
> Return a list of photos matching some criteria. Only photos visible to the calling user will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an API to "search for" images, correct?

Q: What criterion are you searching on?  How are the images "indexed"?

The old Google Image Search API was more than just a "library".  It assumed the images in question were stored in a particular way, and were given (presumably by the user who filed them) searchable index information.

The Flickr API is a good alternative.

Or there are also API's that index based on EXIF information stored in the file.  For example, here's a Perl module that you can use to index and search your own files, independent of Google or Flickr:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::ExifTool

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick and GD for Image API in php and also you must create a php file to handle the requests in example when you send this request to your host :
`http://webservice.com/?q=red+car`
you must get the  `?q=red+car` and then handle it with your API.

for more information please visit [ImageMagic Home Page](http://www.imagemagick.org) and [GD Page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) also